# Opencart orders not importing to ShipStation

Tags: opencart

My Opencart store has stopped importing orders to ShipStation ever since I updated my Journal theme.  I know I probably have to update OpenCart which I am hiring someone to do but I need a workaround till then. Thank you in advance.

**I get this error from ShipStation:**

"An error occurred attempting to update orders: Invalid XML. Error: 'There are multiple root elements. Line 3, position 14.' We received: '

#### Journal Installation Error

You are using an outdated OpenCart 2.x version. Journal only works with the latest Opencart 2.x version.
Please download and install'"

**The error log on my Opencart shipstation backend says this:**
2016-07-20 12:27:06 - PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/garagist/public_html/store/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 23

Journal support said this to fix it and I have no idea how to do that:

You need to edit /shipstation/config.php file and add this line (anywhere in it), so the Journal engine won't be loaded for that extension:

define('BLOCK_JOURNAL', true);

Answer (score 0):

First you installed the wrong version of Journal. I am very familiar with it and I know the developers provide a template for each version in the zip file from codecanyon. Even if you were running 1.5x, it's in there. Fix that problem first.

Second, ShipStation has nothing to do with journal, you have server issues now (probably due to the incorrect version of journal). I've never had to block journal from the ShipStation config file. That's probably why it isn't working.

FYI, I have around 5 shops and over 10 clients running journal and shipstation, no isuses at all ever. Versions range from OC 1.5-2.3.0.2.

You don't need to upgrade, don't pay if you don't have to.

Update: From Journal Directly "Compatible with Opencart: 1.5.4.x / 1.5.5.x / 1.5.6.x / 2.0.x / 2.1.x / 2.2.x / 2.3.x" Seems counterintuitive to support 2.0x if they're going to force you to update your OC installation when the theme is installed doesn't it?

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. 

Do you work on OpenCart websites? Are you for hire?

Comment: You can email me at alex.funari@gmail.com we can talk about your requirements